# Text is in Center altough its aligned left

Tags: html, css

My text "lorum ipsum" is aligned left in CSS. I want to add padding on the right later, but for now it isn't going on the left side, it's in the center. Does anyone know what I created again?

```css
    #ubba {

      font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;

      font-size: 20px;

      font-weight: bold;

      text-align: center;

      padding-left: auto;

      margin-top: auto;

    }

    #besch {

      font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;

      font-size: 20px;

      text-align: left;

      padding-right: 0%;

      padding-left: 0%;

      margin-right: 0%;

      margin-left: 0%;

    }

    * {

      box-sizing: border-box;

      margin: 0px;

      height: auto;

      width: auto;

    }

    body {

      font-family: "Open Sans";

      line-height: 1.618em;

      background: #ecf0f1;

      color: #444;

    }

    .wrapper {

      max-width: 500px;

      width: 100%;

      margin: 0 auto;

    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="ubba">
    <p>Überschrift:</p>
  </div>
  <div id="besch">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: code snippet or jsfiddle? Just post the relevant code ;)

Comment: I am totally new to this stuff and to this forum, I have no Idea what you are saying:(

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.net and (create id there )paste your html and css code and share that link

Comment: Just go to http://www.jsfiddle.net and put in your html but only the html between the body tags. Then add your css.

Comment: Try to be as specific as possible about your problem.

Comment: I didnt knew, i am totally sorry. Ill keep that in mind te next time

Comment: In your html declaration you have create two times <div class="wrapper"> and you haven't closed the first one ,just remove it one time it will be fine

Comment: In my browser you code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's your wrapper that is centered :

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px; <---
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto; <---
}
```

Comment: this changed the Heading which should be in center, but  not the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your paragraph is inside the div wrapper which is set to be

```
.wrapper{
   max-width: 500px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is making any child div width 500px and centering in the middle of screen.
Remove the div `besch` from the div `wrapper`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!--Rest of the div-->
</div>
<div id="besch"><!--Removed this div from the wrapper div, now it is outside-->
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam   voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome, always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are looking to achieve, the paragraph with lorem text appear in the center because it's inside a wrapper container.

You can try to close the wrapper `</div>` tag before the div with the text.

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <!-- all the other content -->
</div>

<div id="besch">
  <p>

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
     sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

  </p>

</div>
```

This is a fiddle with the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/w5qoh0v6/